# The Cross Origin Opener Policy header has been ignored - DJANGO

Tags: django, django-channels, cross-origin-opener-policy

Im making a Chatapp project in Django. I implemented channels and websockets to send and receive message and this worked when i tested using two differents windows in the same browser (one of them in incognito mode), but when i try to test it using another browser i get the following error:

[Cross Origin Opener Policy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48wft.png)

I tried to solve implementing django corsheaders with the following configuration:

[Corsheaders app installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIkm4.png)

[Corsheaders middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28kcg.png)

[Corsheaders settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUYbC.png)

(I know that setting all origins to true its not recommendable but it's just for testing purpouses)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In settings.py, you have to set `SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = None`

Default value is `same-origin`

https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html#std-setting-SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY

https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/01/how-to-set-coep-coop-corp-security-headers-in-django/